# Can I edit my .htaccess to write some WorldPress URL's (custom rewrites)?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slug

So here's the problem: We don't like the fact that WordPress doesn't allow duplicate slugs, even for sub categories meaning we cannot have urls like:

```
product-1/guides
product-1/articles
product-2/guides
product-2/articles
```

That's very annoying! One solution we are considering is setting up our slugs like this:

```
product-1/product-1-guides
product-1/product-1-articles
product-2/product-2-guides
product-2/product-2-articles
```

But in our htaccess - can we use it to pick up such urls and rewrite them as prettier urls which have the product name removed from the sub folder? We don't mind hard coding these as we'll only ever have 5-10 products on the site.

This would keep the WordPress install happy with unique slugs, but the SEO tick in the box with better looking urls.

I just need a hand with the syntax please?

**EDIT 1:**

After looking at the WordPress Rewrite API, I'm failing to get anywhere with what I think is a really simple test. I have the following code in my functions.php which is running as I tested an echo, but no rewriting is taking place?

```
add_action( 'init', 'productRewrites' );

function productRewrites() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^wordpress/james?','index.php?author_name=jwilson','top');
}
```

Nothing happens when I hit:

mysite.com/wordpress/james

**Edit 2:**

Cool I realise I now have to click save each time. The problem I now have is the following does not work not when I use $matches[1] - it only works if I hard code the author_name value (to jwilson for example):

```
function productRewrites() {

    add_rewrite_rule(  
        "writer/([^/]+)/?",  
        "index.php?author_name=$matches[1]",  
        "top");  
}
```

When I use $matches[1] it just returns everything! So clearly isn't using ([^/]+) in the url?!

Comment: why don't you use http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API?

Comment: See Edit 1 please if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reset permalink structure

in order to do that, move to **Settings** -> **Permalinks** and press **Save changes** button

Comment: In a nuteshell, ([^/]+) is not transferring to $matches[1] in my example. If I hard code something in place of $matches[1] I get the desired effect. But I need it to use whatever is in that last part of the url...

Comment: Further - should echo "matches = " . $matches[1] reveal something after the add_rewrite_rule() function? As it's blank.